# How to effectively use an overseas SEO team?

Tags: seo, links, content, backlinks

My company is currently in contract with a 20+ person team in the Philippines, previously used for comment linking and guest blogging spun content articles. This is a practice that we're stopping, but we don't want to sever our team because they work hard, they're really cheap, and they produce excellent accounting and reporting of their actions.

What are ways that we can best put them to use as a link generating or content generating resource? Their English is fair, but not of high enough quality to use them for any direct content creation.

Thanks

Comment: I accepted the answers to the questions that I've asked. I don't particularly think that the answers were the greatest though on all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they can produce high quality comments that actually relate to the things they are commenting on (not spam comments), then that is a great use for a team like that. I know you mentioned that you are stopping the comment linking practice, but that is what I would use them for.

You could also use them to be active in the social media world for you - given they are trained on how to do this well and not spammy.

Another use could be for posting content such as videos to the various video sites, although there are automation tools that can help with this.